# WIN32 Application Solution Error: The Project File Could Not be Loaded. Root Element is Missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions

I was going to program a game of Snake using SFML, and after downloading SFML, I tried to create a WIN32 Windows Application, and when I clicked finish in the Wizard, I got the following error:

> Unable to read the project file "SFML-Snake2.vcxproj".
> C:\Users\arnav_1n7er7u\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props(0,0): The project file could not be loaded.
> Root element is missing.

This can be seen in the following screenshot, although it may be unclear:
[image: Error Image]

So to try and solve this problem, I went to the appropriate directory and opened the file `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` in Notepad. After doing so, I found something unusual: The file was full of whitespace, and the exact whitespace content was as follows:

```
 Whitespace
```

(The word whitespace wasn't written there, I just wrote it for the formatting).

In fact, there were two other files in this directory, and when I looked at them, they were also full of whitespace. I have a feeling that is the problem since it is unlikely Microsoft switched to the [Whitespace Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)), but I have absolutely no idea what is supposed to be in the file. Could I be pointed in the right direction, to see what the problem is, and how to fix the Visual Studio error message so I can create my project?

### UPDATE

Ok, to try and fix the problem, I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015, and instead now downloaded the new Visual Studio 2017. In this, I tried to create another WIN32 Windows Application, and got *the exact same error*, which can be seen as follows:

[image: error in screenshot]

This time, I tried to open the file `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` and now found this content (For some reason I cannot copy and paste it):
[image]

Now I am really confused. For some reason, now I cannot create WIN32 Applications in Visual Studio, whether it is 2015, or 2017. What should I do?

Comment: I think you need to reinstall Visual Studio. I have seen similar after a windows update and after reinstalling VS all was well again.

Comment: But do you know what the problem is? The goal of this question is to find out the problem. I could reinstall Visual Studio if necessary, but I really want to know what the problem is. Visual Studio was working fine before I downloaded SFML, then for some reason I couldn't create a solution.

Comment: No sorry when it happened to me I reinstalled and it worked so I did not spend any time debugging the issue.

Comment: @drescherjm I uninstalled 2015, and now got 2017, and am getting the SAME ERROR (see question above). This tells me that the problem is something bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I figured out how to solve the problem. After reading [this MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b0dd8d2-50c0-4c76-b018-99399edc49a9/vs-errorthe-project-file-could-not-be-loadedroot-element-is-missing?forum=visualstudiogeneral), I followed the accepted answers idea to delete the files in the directory `v4.0`. After doing so, I created a new project, and Visual Studio was able to do so because it generated new files in place of the corrupted ones.